# How to select PayPal checkout layout

Tags: paypal

PayPal provides two different checkout layouts. I would use the oldest layout (so not the enhanced). How can I set this preference? Is there some special variable to do that? Or I should do that from profile settings page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `force_sa=true` in your *calling Url*, you can still use the old layout

Check that 
[Paypal express "order summary" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423458/paypal-express-order-summary-page#answer-23658717)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The new (enhanced) layout is gradually being rolled out. The old one will disappear over time.

Comment: Thanks. I received the same answer by PayPal technical staff few days ago.