# Paypal express "order summary" page

Tags: php, paypal

I'm in the the process of replacing the Free and Standard paypal button with a Express checkout integration. I believe I've done most of the work but I have 2 outstanding questions.

1. When using the old button it redirected me to an order summary page where I could still update the quantity of the product I wanted to buy. With Express checkout it seems that this option has dissapeaed. Whilst the quantity field is still there, it's read-only and can therefore not be altered anymore. Can I make it so this field becomes editable again?
2. When i get redirected to the paypal site after pressing submitting the form is not consistent, I suspect Paypal is in the process of rolling out some updates to this page and is doing some A/B testing to see which layout is performing better but it would be good if someone else could confirm a similiar behaviour and if there's anything that I can do to force a particular layout? I found other posts on this forum but they were posted a while ago hence the recheck.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Express Checkout, its actually a API call to the PayPal server.
If you want to edit the Quantity, you need to change the value `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTYm` using your own logic and send the request to PayPal(quantity is not editable).[Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

2.Actually PayPal has released a new Express Checkout layout.

There are two URL's here:

**Old Layout** : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-24P528268C112244W [image]

**New Layout**: 
https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/2?token=EC-24P528268C112244W
[image]

You can force any layout as you wish.

Comment: Cool, so my thinking was right for the first part of my question, however for the checkout url the server always sends the request as https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC%2d6GY225742X303862F (the preferred layout) but then paypal occasionally redirects it to the new url structure and therefore the new layout.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you can force the old layout by including a "force_sa=true" param in your payment request url. Can't find this documented anywhere, but it seems to work consistently. I asked pp tech support about it and got this response:

*The new express checkout layout is being gradually rolled out, you may have an option to force the layout with the following redirection url format:
'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow/2?token=' to force the new checkout layout, it does the same way as force_sa=true*

Didn't answer my question, but I guess they acknowledged it's a valid way to force a layout and not be at the mercy of their "rollout".

Comment: The parameter mentioned is not a recommended parameter; it's for debugging only and forces your transaction through a different stack, in turn affecting latency and reliability of the PayPal integration. I'd suggest deleting it to avoid confusing others.