# Old paypal checkout layout on express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

when we use paypal standard button, payment receive page shows the new look. but when we try with paypal express checkout, it shows paypals old layout. but again when we choose paypal sandbox for express checkout, again the new look. how can i set new paypal layout for paypal express checkout.

im actually using opminpay for payment processing and i have found a solution
[Paypal express "order summary" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423458/paypal-express-order-summary-page#answer-23658717)

and it works, but i dont know is it recommended or not.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting force_sa shouldn't be needed. In some cases, where features incompatible with the new layout are used ([Instant Update API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/)), there will be fallback to the legacy layout.

Would you be able to post your API call? I just tested the EC flow in both Sandbox & live and I'm getting the new layout.

Try mine:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=pro22_1222868134_biz_api1.paypal.com&PWD=XPBWBJ9AFZ9X748L&SIGNATURE=ABhqmE8JdSxFSHp2C6TGP6yXBWsJANNpoeLALseoabPIe162v-muDlb0&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453010/old-paypal-checkout-layout-on-express-checkout&CANCELURL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453010/old-paypal-checkout-layout-on-express-checkout&AMT=0.01&PAYMENTACTION=Sale
```

Take the token from the response, change the %2d in the token to a - and redirect yourself to checkout:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-47P743568V119643D
```